# UIImage from CALayer in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, calayer

In my application, I have created a `CALayer` (with a few sublayers - the CALayer is composed of shapes added as sublayers).

I am trying to create a `UIImage` that I will be able to upload to a server (I have the code for this).
However, I can't figure out how to add the `CALayer` to a `UIImage`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Sounds like you want to render your layer into a UIImage. In that case, the method below should do the trick. Just add this to your view or controller class, or create a category on CALayer.

**Obj-C**

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, NO, 0);

  [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return outputImage;
}
```

**Swift**

```
func imageFromLayer(layer:CALayer) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, layer.isOpaque, 0)
    layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return outputImage!
}
```

Comment: Exchange for `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, YES, 0);`

Comment: I would recommend using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, layer.opaque, 0);`

Comment: how would you update this to render a portion (given a rect in the layer) of the CALayer to an image and not the entire frame?

Comment: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returns nil

Answer (score 18):

Todd's answer is correct, however for retina screens there should be a little difference:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([layer frame].size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([layer frame].size);

    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```

Comment: Specifying `0` for `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`'s `scale` arg defaults it to use `UIScreen.mainScreen.scale`. _(Per the docs, “The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.”)_  Your answer functionally offers no improvement over @Todd Yandell's.

Answer (score 12):

I have created a Swift extension based for this:

```
extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithLayer(layer: CALayer) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.bounds.size, layer.opaque, 0.0)
        layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return img
    }
}
```

The usage:

```
var gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.colors = [UIColor.redColor().CGColor, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor]
gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

let image = UIImage.imageWithLayer(gradient)
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 version with a little bit of error checking for context.

```
extension UIImage {
  class func image(from layer: CALayer) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.bounds.size, 
  layer.isOpaque, UIScreen.main.scale)

    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }

    // Don't proceed unless we have context
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
      return nil
    }

    layer.render(in: context)
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `defer` to handle the `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()`

Comment: Great suggestion. Updated to user defer.