# UIImage from AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, calayer, avcapturesession

I am trying to grab a still image from a video feed (basically a pause or 'snapshot' functionality). My project is setup using [Benjamin Loulier's template](http://www.benjaminloulier.com/posts/ios4-and-direct-access-to-the-camera). My problem is that even though I am displaying color video on the screen via the `prevLayer` (a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer), I have set the video settings to grayscale so I can't get a UIImage from `customLayer` (a regular CALayer).

I tried using this function given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454356/uiimage-from-calayer-iphone-sdk), but this doesn't work for AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer for some stupid reason (shows up clear/transparent). Does anyone know of a method to save the content of a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer as a UIImage?

Comment: I'm on this as well. Tim's answer might be accurate but still it's not like the layer is "flickering", and there ought to be some point in time where the layer is not blank. Did you figure this out?
I had no great luck attempting to grab image data in `- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection` but if I can get that one right, I'll post the answer.

Comment: Ok this seems that it *should* be correct way of capturing 'UIImage' in captureOutput: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html
Posted as answer.

Comment: How can you set grayscale into custom camera using `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.?

Answer (score 3):

Ok this is my answer, courtesy of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1702/_index.html

One note. `minFrameDuration` is deprecated since iOS 5.0. Not sure of the reason or if there is a replacement.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

// Create and configure a capture session and start it running
- (void)setupCaptureSession 
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    // Create the session
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // Configure the session to produce lower resolution video frames, if your 
    // processing algorithm can cope. We'll specify medium quality for the
    // chosen device.
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    // Find a suitable AVCaptureDevice
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice
                             defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    // Create a device input with the device and add it to the session.
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device 
                                                                    error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handling the error appropriately.
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    // Create a VideoDataOutput and add it to the session
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init] autorelease];
    [session addOutput:output];

    // Configure your output.
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
    dispatch_release(queue);

    // Specify the pixel format
    output.videoSettings = 
                [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] 
                    forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];


    // If you wish to cap the frame rate to a known value, such as 15 fps, set 
    // minFrameDuration.
    output.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 15);

    // Start the session running to start the flow of data
    [session startRunning];

    // Assign session to an ivar.
    [self setSession:session];
}

// Delegate routine that is called when a sample buffer was written
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
         didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
         fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{ 
    // Create a UIImage from the sample buffer data
    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

     < Add your code here that uses the image >

}

// Create a UIImage from sample buffer data
- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer 
{
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0); 

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, 
      bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context); 
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context); 
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    // Release the Quartz image
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}
```