# invalid context 0x0, Creating UIImage from CALayer

Tags: ios, calayer

I am trying to convert a CALayer to an UIImage with code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454356/uiimage-from-calayer-iphone-sdk). Copied here. But when I use it I got tons of error. At first I put it in a NSObject class where I use to store a model. But then I read in the post I am suppose to put it in a controller, view or category of CALayer. I tried putting it in a controller or CALayer and it still doesn't work.

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions([layer frame].size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    else
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([layer frame].size);

    [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outputImage;
}
```

ERROR:

```
<Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetLineWidth: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextMoveToPoint: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextAddArc: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextAddArc: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextAddArc: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextAddArc: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextClosePath: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextDrawPath: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetBaseCTM: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextEndTransparencyLayer: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetAlpha: invalid context 0x0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if your layer parameter is `nil`. Usually a context cannot be created if the size has either width = 0 or height = 0 (or both).