# How to save a masked image in iOS

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, mask, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

This is what I am doing to mask an image.. This is working fine.. My problem is that self.imgView.image is not the masked image.. How can I retrieve masked images? Thanks.

```
- (void) setClippingPath:(UIBezierPath *)clippingPath : (UIImageView *)imgView {

    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = self.imgView.frame;
    maskLayer.path = [clippingPath CGPath];
    maskLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

    self.imgView.layer.mask = maskLayer;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to covert a CALayer to a UIImage. It's from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3454613/749786

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([layer frame].size);

  [layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
  UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return outputImage;
}
```

Comment: Here is my **code**

`let maskLayer = CASharpLayer()`

`maskLayer.path = aPath.cgPath`

`maskLayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor`

`self.imageView.layer.mask = maskLayer`

That's swift 3.

How can I get masked image?

Comment: @Eric do you set `self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how in Swift 5.4.

```
func image(from layer: CALayer?) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(layer?.frame.size ?? CGSize.zero)

    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        layer?.render(in: context)
    }
    let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return outputImage
}
```