# How to set navigation bar gradient color in ios 7/8

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the navigation and foot bar to a dark black grey gradient color.
I see that the way to change the bar color is .navigationbar.barTintColor.
That does work if I just want to change the color, but I don't know how to put a gradient color in there.

I was able to create a gradient color for the background of view (using cagradientlayer), but I can't seem to set it to nav bar background.

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

so when I create the caGradientLayer, and set the bar.layer nothing happens.

I tried CRGradientNavigationBar and I am getting stuck.  The bar color changes... but my normal root screen doesn't load... I just see a white background

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CRGradientNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];

    UIColor *firstColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:42.0f/255.0f blue:104.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    UIColor *secondColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:90.0f/255.0f blue:58.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstColor, secondColor, nil];
    // or NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)UIColorFromRGB(0xf16149).CGColor, (id)UIColorFromRGB(0xf14959).CGColor, nil];

    [[CRGradientNavigationBar appearance] setBarTintGradientColors:colors];
    [[navigationController navigationBar] setTranslucent:NO]; // Remember, the default value is YES.

     MasterViewController *viewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] init];
    [navigationController setViewControllers:@[viewController]];

    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];

    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

Comment: take a look here https://github.com/chroman/CRGradientNavigationBar

Comment: Why you don't create a gradient color image and add it in the navigation bar? @solarissf

Comment: i just added code I used to create the cagradientlayer, are you saying I should make this an image?  if so how do I do that

Comment: @Priyatham51, I am trying  the crgradient and am stuck

Comment: @solarissf what is error?

Comment: no error, just a white background, instead of loading my masterviewcontroller with all the objects I have on it.  maybe the white background is just covering them?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a background image.  Make a horizontally stretchable image of your gradient (using your favorite graphics software, or Quartz2D if you want to generate the gradient at runtime).  Apply the image to the bar's background using -setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics: (preferably via the appearance proxy).

Comment: how would I create an image?  I don't have graphics software.  And quartz looks pretty complicated

Comment: Quartz is not that awful :) And if you already know of to create a `CAGradientLayer`, just make a `UIImage` from it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454356/uiimage-from-calayer-iphone-sdk)