# Create gradient background for SKScene (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, linear-gradients, skscene

I'm having trouble finding a way to create a gradient background for an `SKScene`.  I have tried using `CAGradientLayer` but to no success.  The only way I know to change the background is to use, for example, `backgroundColor = SKColor.cyan`.  But I want to just create a linear gradient to make the background of my scene look nice and smooth.  As of now this is what I have tried and it does not work.

**CODE:**

```
    let gradientBG = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientBG.frame = (self.view?.bounds)!
    gradientBG.colors = [SKColor.black, SKColor.cyan]
    gradientBG.locations = [0.0, 0.5]
    gradientBG.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
    gradientBG.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientBG.zPosition = 1

    self.scene?.view?.layer.addSublayer(gradientBG)
```

is there any way to do this using `CAGradientLayer`? Am I missing anything? If you have any suggestions, I would love to hear.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a UIView object with CAGradientLayer.  Then convert it into an image.

Comment: No need to make it a UIView, look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454356/uiimage-from-calayer-iphone-sdk, you go from CGLayer -> UIImage -> SKTexture -> SKSpriteNode

Comment: You can also create a gradient background with `CGGradient`