# Obtaining UIImage with UIView with a CALayer sublayer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer

I have read and gone over:
[UIImage from CALayer - iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454356/uiimage-from-calayer-iphone-sdk/44292563#44292563)

But when I try to use `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` I only seem to get my sublayer in the returned `UIImage` that I added to my `UIView`. I would like the returned `UIImage` to have both the camera feed in my `UIView` as well as the `CALayer` sublayer I added to the `UIView`.

I set up the camera feed in my `UIView`, drawing my sublayer, adding my sublayer, then setting up my Context with:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(myView.layer.frame.size,myView.layer.isOpaque,UIScreen.man.scale)
```

all in `viewDidLoad()`.

Then in a later button action I try:

```
let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIImageWriteToSavePhotosAlbum(img!,nil,nil,nil)
```

But the saved image only has my sublayer with the drawing I made and not the camera feed. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of describing what you do, show actual relevant code.

Comment: I am pretty sure the answer to this question lies in using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput() but all of the example code blocks I see create functions that take a CMSampleBuffer to create a UIImage but I don't know where to get this buffer from?

Comment: After some more digging I found that if your class extends AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate and you create a func captureOutput(_ output:AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) then the machine will call this function for you and place the data in the sampleBuffer variable. Hope this helps others. Now to figure out how to lay my sublayers I drew on top of this image.....