# How to change the bottom toolbar background on iOS 16 with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, background, toolbar

Since iOS 16, we can customize the background of a navigationBar easily with:

```
.toolbarBackground(barBackgroundGradient, for: .navigationBar)
.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
```

It's working well.

However, I can't make it working for a bottom toolbar:

```
.toolbarBackground(barBackgroundGradient, for: .bottomBar)
.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .bottomBar)
```

It's compiling but nothing changes on the app.

Looking at [developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbarbackground(_:for:)-5ybst?changes=_6), it should work...

I tried also that:

```
.toolbarBackground(barBackgroundGradient, for: .navigationBar, .bottomBar)
```

It doesn't change anything.

Any idea ?

Comment: Hi, may I ask, did you eventually find a solution to this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I think it has to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching for an answer to a similar problem, my solution was to create an **UIToolbar extension** like this:

```
extension UIToolbar {
    static func changeAppearance(clear: Bool) {
        let appearance = UIToolbarAppearance()
        
        if clear {
            appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        } else {
            appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
        }

        // customize appearance for your needs here
        appearance.shadowColor = .clear
        appearance.backgroundColor = .clear
        appearance.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "imageName")
        
        UIToolbar.appearance().standardAppearance = appearance
        UIToolbar.appearance().compactAppearance = appearance
        UIToolbar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

So, I think, in your case it's possible to create your *barBackgroundGradient* with **CAGradientLayer** first, then [turn it to **UIImage**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454356/uiimage-from-calayer-in-ios) and use it in *appearance.backgroundImage*.

After all that call **changeAppearance** inside the initializer of your View:

```
init() {
    UIToolbar.changeAppearance(clear: true)
}
```

Probably, not the most elegant way, especially concerning the gradient part, so maybe you will find some other solution before Apple will fix this, as it seems to be a bug.